# Agregar clases opcionales a React

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

En React quiero agregar una clase a mi  ejemplo:

```
<input type="text" className={'form-control'} className={ isValid ? 'is-valid' : "is-invalid"}
```

Cuando mi **state isValid** sea valido, agregar la clase 'is-valid' o cuando no 'is-invalid'.
cual es el *objetivo* de esto?
de que al mismo tiempo quiero agregar la clase **form-control** por ejemplo:

```
<input type="text" className={ isValid ? 'is-valid form-control' : 'is-invalid form-control'}
```

Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma para manejar el agregado de esta clase ya que lo que requiero es no repetir la clase form-control en las 2 condiciones, como tengo en mente es realizarlo de la siguiente forma:

```
class MiComponentExample extends Component {

   render(){
    const myStyle = 'form-control ' + (isValid ? 'is-valid' : 'is-invalid');

    return(
    ...
    <input className = {myStyle} .... />
    ...
    )
   }
}
```

el ejemplo lo pongo porque en angular puedo manejarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
<input class="form-control" [ngClass]={ 'is-valid' : isValid , 'is-invalid': !isValid } />
```

& el resultado es que termina agregando la clase form-control, y una de las clases is-valid|is-invalid
Que manera correcta podria utilizar para agregar clases como el ejemplo mostrado? o que manera utilizan para este tipo casos que se les presentan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias utilizar un array de Strings & despues realizar un join()... juntar todos los elementos de el array por el valor de .join(' ') para que no ponga una ',' cuando se representen las clases.

```
<input
   className={[isValid ? 'is-valid':'is-invalid', 'form-control' ].join(' ')} .../>
```

Otra manera de realizarlo que se mira mas limpia es de la siguiente:

```
<input
   className={`form-control ${isValid ? 'is-valid':'is-invalid'}`} .../>
```

me gusta la manera en como se representa en Angular, pero tambien esta muy buena la manera de hacerlo en React.